# Slow http file sharing

Tags: apache, xampp

Using XAMPP I am sharing files over my local network using Apache.

To expose a directory I have added the following to my conf\httpd.conf file. This works, but I am only getting 550 KB/s (4.4 Mb/s) throughput. This is slower than I can download from the internet. How do I configure the server so that I can get closer to the theoretical maximum of throughput 65 Mbps.

(I'm aware that I wont the full 65 Mbps, but I'd like to be getting 50 not 4.4 which is unacceptable)

```
<Directory "D:\MySharingDirectory">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<IfModule alias_module>
Alias /MySharingDirectory "D:\MySharingDirectory"
</IfModule alias_module
```

>

Can some one please help me configure the Apache server to file share over HTTP more efficiently?

Comment: What tool are you using to measure your apache's download speed? I recommend `curl` or `wget` with redirecting the output to `/dev/null`, or in your case (Windows) to `NUL`. (First impulse was "use Linux". ;-)

Comment: 1) FreeDownloadManager, and 2) I have written a multi-threaded http download client for android. If you are suggesting redirecting to /dev/null as a joke like BSOH then haha.

Comment: No, I'm suggesting throwing the output away (/dev/null or NUL) so your  speed measurement won't be hindered by possible I/O-problems while storing the response on disk. I know of no default bandwidth limit in Apache. You could also try copying or rsyncing some files on the filesystem in question to find out if it poses any limitations.

Comment: Well thanks but no, I'm not interested in measuring, I know the disk does not have response problems, because it does not have response problems when doing anything else. I'm interested in copying real files over the network. I know the capacity of the network. I have a bottle neck in the server and I'm looking for help in configuring the server memory or caching or mtu's or something like that. If you know of any Apache configuration which will increase http get filesharing throughput I'd be delighted to hear.

Comment: Conversely if you can explain why it is slow, that would be fine too. Thanks

Comment: Just a few educated guesses. Disable any CustomLog directives. Also disable any modules you're not using. Is the transfer still slow when you initiate it on the server itself, thus eliminating the network?

Comment: Okay, you got it. After a reboot the loopback is up to 5000KB/s. So the issue is on point to point though my hub. Ill have to put a better spec local network hub in place. Thanks for helping, create a answer saying to do the local file test removing the network..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default bandwidth limit in Apache. So the bandwidth issue could be located anywhere between your download tool and Apache. Try initiating the download on the server itself, thus eliminating the network.

Comment: For anyone else reading this it is worth mentioning that while my home wireless network is 56Mb/s -> the throughput point to point on the network should be 3400KB/s each way. It isn't ... it's 600Kb/s, and on a 65Mb/s network it's proportionality bigger... Perleone is correct but apart from my math being wrong, I still do not understand why the network does not perform to specification.